# Synching two table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Hi I have two database servers (2 different machine, but on same network).
I have one table in Database_1 and same table in Database_2.

Only Table in DB_1 will be updated by user, table in DB_2 will be used by other user for read only.

I want to program something which can copy the updated record from table in DB_1 to DB_2. I want to make it event based, something like whenever someone insert a record in Table@DB_1, I will get the same the record in Table@DB_2.

Can someone suggest me something?

Comment: You've only mentioned inserts. Should UPDATEs and DELETEs also flow to Table@DB_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size, frequency of updates, and complexity of your systems, Replication may be the answer you need. [Transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179424(v=SQL.80).aspx) sounds the most suitable, from the little detail provided.

Answer (score 0):

How time sensitive is the data?  There are two possibilities with this for me.

Suggestion 1:  Have triggers to keep the data synced to the table on a linked server.

Suggestion 2:  Have a DTS/SSIS package that keeps DB_2 in sync. Schedule the package to run every minute or five minutes depending on what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/059240.html).

> "Oracle GoldenGate provides real-time, log-based change data capture, and delivery between heterogeneous systems. Using this technology, it enables cost-effective and low-impact real-time data integration and continuous availability solutions."